# Using sessionStorage to remember addClass - only works after browser reload

Tags: jquery, addclass, session-storage

I'm using the code below in an external .js file which is being loaded in the head to set and remember whether a button has been clicked and add a new class to it if it has.

This works fine when the page is force reloaded by the browser but it's very temperamental when content is loaded via Ajax (which is how 99% of my site loads the content).

I know this is just a case of one or two doc ready's but I'm having trouble working out where to put them.

What I've tried..

1) wrapping all of the functions in one `$(document).ready(function(){` I'm not even sure that this is advisable but it didn't make any difference anyway.

2) wrapping various functions in `$(document).ready(function(){` but again nothing seems to make it work reliably.

Could somebody please advise the best course of action?

Cheers ;)

```
function loadInCartBt() {
itemInCart = sessionStorage.inCart;
return itemInCart
? JSON.parse(itemInCart) : [];
}

function saveInCartBt(inCart) {
sessionStorage.inCart = JSON.stringify(inCart);
}

function addbt2Cart(chbuyBt) {
$(chbuyBt).addClass('chbuyincart');
var inCart = loadInCartBt();
inCart.push(chbuyBt.id);
saveInCartBt(inCart);
}

function removeBtFromCart(chbuyBt) {
$(chbuyBt).removeClass('chbuyincart');
var inCart = loadInCartBt();
inCart.pop(chbuyBt.id);
saveInCartBt(inCart);
}


$(function(){
$.each(loadInCartBt(), function(i, chbuyBt){
$('#'+chbuyBt).addClass('chbuyincart');
});

$('.chbuyBt').on('click', function() {
var chbuyBt = this;
if (loadInCartBt().indexOf(chbuyBt.id) < 0) {
  addbt2Cart(chbuyBt);
} else {
  removeBtFromCart(chbuyBt);
}
});
});

function clearSessionStorage() {
sessionStorage.clear();
}
```

For clarity this is what the html for the button looks like :

```
<div class="chart-buy"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tk450" class="chbuyBt" onclick="addToBasket('450','track')"><span class="ch-buy-price">1.39</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok couldn't work it out so ended up storing the code above in a different file called local.js and calling it in the footer of my page like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/local.js"></script>
```

Works perfectly!

Also changed sessionStorage to localStorage as it's a bit more robust.

Still would like the answer to my original question if anybody knows though.